# Is there any rule about the ideal ratio between the number of samples and attributes for proper regression model building?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, inference, dataset

I am working on a regression problem and for that I am removing the identified outliers. I am curious to know if I should try to maintain a ratio between no. of samples and no. of attributes while removing outliers. Please suggest in this regard and if there is any reference paper which discusses about the ideal (or minimum) no. of samples per attribute.

Comment: When "removing outliers", are you sure that these are really invalid or erroneous? Removing observations that are valid and meaningful is not good practice, and just because a point appears "outlying" it doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: Re your question it'd be helpful to say how many observations and attributes you actually have. There is no fixed rule for sure, however with 20 observations per attribute you should normally be fine (unless your attributes are categorical with lots of categories). But if you remove valid observations just because of their "outlying" position, you will bias your analysis.